# In fine-uploader. It shows "Processing..." after upload is finished

Tags: fine-uploader

I am using fine-uploader to upload files directly to S3 in chunks.

It works fine in most of the cases, but sometimes I face a strange issue. After the upload reaches completion. It keeps on showing "Processing..." forever.

What can be the possible reason for this?

[image: You can see the example below..]

Answer (score 0):

A "processing..." message that never disappears when using Fine Uploader S3 indicates either that S3 is taking a very long time to combine the file chunks, or Fine Uploader may be waiting for a response to [the upload success request](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-s3.html#uploadSuccess) it sends to your server once S3 has combined all the file chunks.

You can find out for sure by examining the network/request traffic in your browser's developer tools.